# Find maximum of each cell array element efficiently

Tags: matlab

We have foe example a 3x5 `cell` array where each element is a matrix. Can we find the maximum of each cell element, i.e, a matrix, and store the corresponding value in a new 3x5 matrix? All this without for loops. Bellow there is the naive way.

Example:

```
a = rand(5,6);
b = rand(7,6);
c = rand(7,9);
d = rand(27,19);
CellArray = cell(2,2);
CellArray{1}=a;
CellArray{2}=b;
CellArray{3}=d;
CellArray{4}=c;

MaxResults = nan(size(CellArray));
for i=1:numel(size(CellArray))
    MaxResults(i) = max(max(CellArray{i})); 
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note that in your code you could replace `max(max(CellArray{i}))` by `max(CellArray{i}(:))` (as in @Jonas's answer), which is probably faster

Comment: Also I highly doubt you want your loop to go to `numel(size(CellArray))` but rather to just `numel(CellArray)`

Comment: Yes you are right Dan.

Comment: @LuisMendo: `max(max(CellArray{i}))` is actually faster than `max(CellArray{i}(:))` for large inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not guaranteed to be that much more efficient (until Matlab decides to multithread it), but you can use `cellfun` like this:

```
MaxResults = cellfun(@(x)max(x(:)), CellArray)
```